# Patch Beamer command \addtobeamertemplate to work with predefined option

Tags: beamer

From Beamer documentation I found that we can create templates with `predefined options` `\setbeamertemplate{⟨element name⟩}[⟨predefined option⟩]⟨args⟩` which is very convenient to switch from one template to another.
But, also from the documentation, it seems that the command `\addtobeamertemplate{⟨element name⟩}{⟨pre-text⟩}{⟨post-text⟩}`, that I used to extend my templates, does not accept such predefined option.
In other word, it can only add code to the current template.
While, I found found very useful to add code to a stored template.

So my question is: is there a way to add code to a stored template ? or to patch  `\addtobeamertemplate` to applied on a template with 'predefined option' ?

Here is an example (where I agree the `\addtobeamertemplate` is pointless since I could directly add stuff in the template definition, but it is an example):

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{normal}[1][]
{%
    TEST 1
}

\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{fancy}[1][]
{%
    SUPER STYLE TEST 1
}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[normal]
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{% pre patch
}{%post patch
 IS UGLY
}

%%%% An workaround attempt not working  
% \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[fancy]
% \addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{% pre patch
% }{%post patch
%  IS BEAUTIFUL
% }
% \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[normal]

\begin{document} %

\begin{frame}{title}
   normal ugly frame
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[fancy]
\begin{frame}{title}
   fancy frame that I would like prettier
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{title}
   normal frame still ugly
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[normal]
\begin{frame}{title}
   normal frame that should stay uglier
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know some code which occurs in the template, you can patch it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{normal}[1][]
{%
    TEST 1
}

\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{fancy}[1][]
{%
    SUPER STYLE TEST 1
}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\xpatchcmd\csname beamer@@tmpop@background canvas@normal\endcsname{%
  1
}{%
  1 is ugly
}{}{}
\makeatother


\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[normal]

\begin{document} %

\begin{frame}{title}
   normal ugly frame
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[fancy]
\begin{frame}{title}
   fancy frame that I would like prettier
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{title}
   normal frame still ugly
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[normal]
\begin{frame}{title}
   normal frame that should stay uglier
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

*How to figure out the full name of the macro? Quick and dirty hack: try to define an already existing template and the error message will conveniently tell you the full macro name :)*

Comment: (the easier approach probably is to just copy the code of the predefined template and redefine it under a new name with the desired modifications....)

Comment: Thank you for this option. However, I don't know always the code occurring the  templates (because it can vary). Is there a way to adapt your suggestion in that case ?

Comment: @R.N Copy the original template definition and redefine it under a new name, including your changes.

Comment: I do understand your point and you are right. But, I would like to avoid this option which is not very elegant nor convenient (in my case). However, considering your answer, I am thinking that I can maybe add a specific comment line in my templates that could serves as a hook for `xpatchcmd`. What do you think ?

Comment: @R.N If these are your own templates, why not directly use a hook in them?

Comment: I did not though about it and I don't know how to make a hook that can used multiple time, this is why I though about `addtobeamertemplate` or patchs.

Comment: @R.N Real latex hooks would probably be more elegant, but just a quick concept of proof: `\newcommand{\BackgroundNormalHook}{}
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{normal}[1][]{TEST 1 \BackgroundNormalHook}
\apptocmd{\BackgroundNormalHook}{is ugly}{}{}`

Comment: @R.N With real hooks: `\ActivateGenericHook{backgroundCanvasNormal}
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{normal}[1][]{TEST 1 \UseHook{backgroundCanvasNormal}}
\AddToHook{backgroundCanvasNormal}{is ugly}`